# Error while using using two handler in Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to use two handler in the component, onload of the component, but its giving error, what is the way of using two handlers in lightning component,

Here is my markup:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}"/>
<aura:handler name="loadData" value="{!this}" action="{!c.loadData}"/>
```

Using `doinit` only its working fine, but just by adding another `<aura:handler>` it gives error. I don't have anything in my `loadData` method (I removed everything just to check), below is the code:

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
     //my functionality
},
loadData : function (component, event, helper) {
      //my functionality
}
```

I've got something like `event="aura:doneWaiting"` and `event="aura:waiting"` but not sure when to use it.

Here is the error

[image]

Comment: Any time you have an error message, you should include it ***verbatim***. Telling us you got an error but not sharing what it is makes it much more difficult to help you.

Comment: Also note that error messages are significantly more searchable (and therefore useful) when included as text rather than images.

Comment: That's actually a common error, but here its not the error, its something else, so that why posted the text.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_valueInit.htm) only one event handler for the `this` event should be present.

> A component can have only one  tag to handle
>   this event. Setting value="{!this}" marks this as a value event. You
>   should always use this setting for an init event.

If you wanted to invoke another method from the `this` event handler, you should be using the helper here.

controller:

```
doinit : function(component, event, helper) {
     //my functionality
     helper.loadData(component, event, helper);
},
```

helper:

```
loadData : function (component, event, helper) {
      //my functionality
}
```

Comment: So what If I want to use two handler with {!this}, can I use that ?

Comment: No, you cannot have two handlers for {!this} event.

Comment: And what would be the reason to have 2 handlers for the same event ?